# How to set a child element display property to none when the parent element is set to block

Tags: javascript, html, list, bootstrap-4, display

I have a Bootstrap Jumbotron wrapping a Bootstrap list.
The Jumbotrom is set to hide by default:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="shoppingCart" style="display: none">
  <h1 class="display-4" >Checkout</h1>
  <p class="lead" id = "checkOutIntro">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>Your shoppping cart :</p>
```

Each list element is also set as hidden.
The idea is to make a list element visible by a JS function when required.

```
<!--Each item will be hidden until its populated by purchase.js-->
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style="display: none" id = "purchaseItem 2">
Dapibus ac facilisis in
<span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
```

The function changes the display attribute of the list element:

```
document.getElementById("purchaseItem " + purchase.paintingNumber).style.display = "block";
```

However when I make the parent Jumbotrom div visible the entire list is also visible, regardless of the list element inline `display:none` command.

Is it possible to set a child element display property to none / block when the parent element display property is set to an opposite value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try overriding other external definitions by using **!important** tag after the property

```
document.getElementById("purchaseItem " + purchase.paintingNumber).style.display = "block !important";
```

read more about it at  [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)